# Present View Controller From outside of controller with out passing self reference

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I have an application in which there are admins and normal user where admin can remove users. Once the user is removed I need to show the you have been removed. I get apn from server based on which i have to show him the view controller explaining why this is happening and also clear all his data. Currently once i receive the apn i post a notification which is received by view controller from which this view controller is presented.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AccountLockedController") as! AccountLockedController
self.present(viewController, animated: true) {
            print("Presented")
        }
```

Now the size of project is growing so now i pass the reference of self to a function to basically do the same

```
userInactivated(viewController: self)
```

From all view Controller the in a function is present the Accountlocked View Controller

Is there a way for me to direcly present the account locked view controller which out current view controller reference or can i get this value I found this but

```
if let presentingViewController = self.appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.presentingViewController {}
```

But there is no self.appDelegate in a non view controller class

Any help is appreciated thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this extension

```
extension UIApplication
{
    class func topViewController(_ base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {
        if let nav = base as? UINavigationController
        {
            let top = topViewController(nav.visibleViewController)
            return top
        }

        if let tab = base as? UITabBarController
        {
            if let selected = tab.selectedViewController
            {
                let top = topViewController(selected)
                return top
            }
        }

        if let presented = base?.presentedViewController
        {
            let top = topViewController(presented)
            return top
        }
        return base
    }

}
```

then you can use this code to present your controller from anywhere

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AccountLockedController") as! AccountLockedController
UIApplication. topViewController()?.present(viewController, animated: true) {
            print("Presented")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should log out user first and set your `window?.rootViewController` to `Accountlocked View Controller`

You can access app delegate using `let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate`

If you don't want to set is as `rootViewController` with `Accountlocked View Controller`, log out the user and set `rootViewController` to your app's non logged in user landing screen and present `Accountlocked View Controller`.